# Correctly show application icon in Gtk

Tags: gtk, icons

I have created an icon file and placed it in `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/apps/scalable` but how do I set it as the icon for my application? I have tried `set_default_icon_name` and `set_icon_name` but nether had any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you run `gtk-update-icon-cache` after installing the icon? [Here's](http://ptomato.name/advanced-gtk-techniques/html/desktop-file.html) a tutorial on installing icons and desktop files which you may find useful.